# Jquery combining tags

Tags: jquery

How can I combine two similar tags using jquery?

```
<div class="case">
  <span>hey</span>
</div>
<div class="case">
  <span>there</span>
</div>
```

into:

```
<div class="case">
  <span>hey</span>
  <span>there</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$( "span" ).unwrap();
$( "span" ).wrapAll( "<div class='case' />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case">
  <span>hey</span>
</div>
<div class="case">
  <span>there</span>
</div>
```

use [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) and [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

> Description: Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.
>
> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

Comment: True, but how can I focus only on the case span element. I need something use $(".case").children() but it won't work since unwrap causes wrapAll to not work. Thanks, I will try to work with this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gurdio,

I found that this will work while being specific to the .case class.

```
$(".case").wrapAll( "<div class='case'/>");
$(".case>.case").children().unwrap();
```